# Variational Dropout in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement an LSTM neural network based on the variational RNN architecture defined in Yarin Gal and Zoubin Ghahramani's paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.05287.pdf using Keras with Tensorflow backend in Python.

The idea is basically to apply the same dropout mask at each time step, **both on the input/output connections and the recurrent connections**, as shown in this figure:

[image: figure]

Reading the Keras documentation, I see that we can apply dropout on LSTM cells with the arguments `dropout` and `recurrent_dropout`. My first question is:

1. Using only these arguments, is the same dropout mask applied at each time step? And if no, is there a way of doing it?

Then, I also see that we can create a Dropout layer after an LSTM cell, and using the `noise_shape` argument, we can force the layer to apply the same dropout mask at each time. I have done this by setting `noise_shape=(K.shape(x)[0], 1, K.shape(x)[2])`. My second question is:

2. Does the Dropout layer applies on recurrent connections if put after an LSTM layer?

To summarize, I have the feeling that with the first method, we can apply dropout on the recurrent connections but we cannot apply the same dropout mask at each time step, and that with the second method, it's the opposite. Am I wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want that "both masks" are equal through all steps, right? Or you want that "both masks are equal to each other"?

Comment: Hi! Yes I want the recurrent dropout mask and the "classical" one to be equal through all time steps, as shown in the picture.

Comment: Again, do you want them to be "equal to each other"? **Or** the two can be different, but not change through time?

Comment: No, and I don't see how they could be equal to each other since their shapes are not the same. Again, I just want exactly the same structure as in the figure: one mask on input/output that stays the same through all time steps, and one recurrent mask that also stays the same through all time steps.